# When I try to use an exception to catch Division by Zero, it still gives me an error?

Tags: python, error-handling

In python, I tried this code:

```
def divide(a=1, b=1):
    try:
        return a / b
    except b == 0:
        return 'Cannot divide by zero eg: %s / %s' % (a, b)

print(divide(1, 0))
```

and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/Jethro/Coding/pythonProject2/main.py", line 8, in <module>
print(divide(1, 0))
File "E:/Jethro/Coding/pythonProject2/main.py", line 4, in divide
except b == 0:
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This is not how `try`/`except` works. You need to define the exception(s) after `except`:

```
def divide(a=1, b=1):
    try:
        return a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 'Cannot divide by zero eg: %s / %s' % (a, b)
    
divide(1,0)
```

Alternatively, use a simple test on `b`:

```
def divide(a=1, b=1):
    if b==0:
        return 'Cannot divide by zero eg: %s / %s' % (a, b)
    else:
        return a/b
    
divide(1,0)
```

Comment: To add to this, what happens for you OP is that `b == 0` will be evaluated to either `True` or `False`, which aren't types of exceptions.